# Отделяется ли запятой деепричастный оборот, стоящий в конце данного предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Вот предложение: "*Они вышли из магазина() весело смеясь*". Нужна ли здесь запятая? Мне кажется, что нет. Вышли (как?) весело смеясь. Но я сомневаюсь в верности этого предположения.

Answer (score 2):

**Они вышли из магазИна, весело смеЯсь.**

В данном примере деепричастный оборот обособляется, о чем говорят следующие факты.

1) **Это оборот**, а не одиночное деепричастие, а **обороты обособляются значительно чаще**. (Это вполне понятно, так как одиночному деепричастию легче занять позицию наречия и вписаться в предложение без обособления, чем деепричастному обороту).

2) **Оборот не входит в основное содержание предложения** "Они вышли из магазИна", то есть предложение на этом можно закончить. Оборот передает добавочную информацию: и при этом весело смеялись.

3) В предложение **два тонических ударения,** в связи с предшествующим ударным словом "из магазИна" **перед оборотом делается пауза.**

**Пример без обособления:**

Что, сударь, плачете? живите-ка **смеясь** (А. С. Грибоедов).

Comment: "Обороты обособляются значительно реже." Описка? Предположительно, должно быть: "Обороты почти всегда обособляются".

Comment: Да, спасибо, исправлено.

Answer (score 1):

**Они вышли из магазина, весело смеясь.**

Розенталь объясняет, когда деепричастный оборот не обособляется:

> Примечание. Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется:
>   1) если деепричастный оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания: Она сидела чуть откинув голову (Марк.) — указывается, что она не просто сидела, а сидела с откинутой головой; Жили Артамоновы ни с кем не знакомясь (М. Г.) — важно, что жили без всяких знакомств; Это упражнение делают стоя на вытянутых носках — смысл сообщения в том, каким образом делают упражнение; Старик шёл прихрамывая на правую ногу; Студенты приобретают знания не только слушая лекции, но и выполняя практические работы; Писал он обычно наклонив голову; Не унижая себя говорю, а говорю с болью в сердце (М. Г.); Огромного роста, редкой силы, волосатый, он ходил по земле наклоня голову, как бык (М. Г.); Яков сидел опустив ноги (М. Г.).

На мой взгляд, у Вас не тот случай. Не шли смеясь, а вышли (сов. вид, событие уже произошло) и смеются.